# Is K-Nearest Neighbor and Nearest Neighbor algorithm the same?

Tags: algorithms, k-nearest-neighbour

Does anyone know if there is a difference between K nearest neighbor (KNN) and nearest neighbor algorithm (NN)? And if they are how are they different?

So far all I know is that NN is unsupervised learning while KNN is supervised learning.

Comment: When you say "NN is unsupervised learning", are you reading NN as neural networks rather than nearest neighbours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Nearest Neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) (NN) is a catch-all term for a whole family of methods that use search among the neighbors for different purposes. [Scikit-learn named a whole module like this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html). [$k$NN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) is a regression and classification algorithm that works by searching the database to find $k$ points the most similar to an example and average them to make the prediction. The other use may be in a [content-based recommender system](https://%20https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/content-based/basics), where we are searching for some number of similar products to present them as recommendations. In both cases, we use the *nearest neighbors search* as a workhorse. Also, keep in mind that it is not a single algorithm, but there are multiple algorithms and their implementations for it, including exact and approximate ones (e.g. [Spotify's Annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)).